# how can I run the benchmark test?

Tags: benchmarking, activemq-classic

This post has NOT been accepted by the mailing list yet.

I want to run the benchmark test, and the activemq version is 5.6.0.

And I follow the steps

[image]

but the maven says:  Unknown lifecycle phase "server".

So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yeah that doc is outdated.

With the ActiveMQ distribution there is an example you can use for performance testing.

In the root of the ActiveMQ distribution (eg such as 5.6.0)

```
cd examples
ant
```

And it display a usage page

Then you can use the ant producer to send in a lot of messages. And ant consumer to receive the messages.

Comment: I logged a ticket to improve the docs: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4061